# how to create a corner button with IB?

Tags: iphone, button, interface

we can set a corner button with code very easily
for example
view.layer.cornerRadius = 9.

but i want to finish it with Interface Build

I can't find it in IB for a long time

can you help me ?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

No you can't, you can only do the cornerRadius in code.